# Upload image to Flickr using Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, image, upload, flickr, cs3

I have a requirement of uploading an image to flickr through an application in Flash AS 2.0. I am not clear with the authentication process. Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start with something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/as3flickrlib/

Alternatively, you might want to code your own solution using flickr's built in api without re-using someone else's code:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: That library is in AS3, not in AS2. The api link is a good start of course.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah. Missed the AS2 request. That's not going to be a pretty task.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that is not super-easy. It involves working through Flickr's auth procedures before you can send the file... using a pre-built library (as Paul suggested) will make your life easier.

But if you're adventurous, dive into the flickr API and make the auth happen, from there it's smooth sailing to get uploading working!